# Conflicting 'ztable' models in application

Tags: django

I have a DB on PostgreSQL. I automatically generated models by the help of `inspectdb` tool. But when I run my application, there is an error: `Conflicting 'ztable' models in application 'login': <class 'login.models.ZTable'> and <class 'login.models.Ztable'>.` What's the matter?

Also I have one ore question: if I generate models by the help of inspectdb, this tool will fill these models with data from db?

Comment: Show the model file generated.

Comment: Be careful, `inspectdb` is not perfect, you must generally make some fix after.

Comment: in DB there is two tables: z_table and ztable, but it generate two models with same names

Comment: i would never generate models with any tool.

Comment: doniyor, ok, guy. Can you help me then? I have one problem: I have a DB with many tables, one of tat table is 'zusers', where stores usernames and passwords and some additional data. I have a login form. And I must check if there is such user in database? How to implement it?

Comment: Have you worked through the Django tutorial yet? If not, I would highly recommend you do so. Django has it's own concept of what a user is and has built in classes, methods and forms to control authentication. You'll need to be familiar with how those work in order to know what to do to migrate your existing table of users to be compatible with Django. This site is for getting help with *specific* programming problems, not for strategies or to have someone post a complete example of how to do your work for you.